# redirect_to redirects to wrong path with commas in it "http://myapp.com, myapp.com/foo"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using rails version

```
    rails (5.1.7)
      actioncable (= 5.1.7)
      actionmailer (= 5.1.7)
      actionpack (= 5.1.7)
      actionview (= 5.1.7)
      activejob (= 5.1.7)
      activemodel (= 5.1.7)
      activerecord (= 5.1.7)
      activesupport (= 5.1.7)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.1.7)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
```

Using `config/enviroments/production.rb`

```
  config.app_domain                            = 'myapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options     = { host: 'myapp.com', protocol: 'https' }
```

the

```
Rails.logger.debug("foo_path=#{foo_path}")
Rails.logger.debug("foo_url=#{foo_url}")
redirect_to foo_path
```

in controller action returns

```
D, [2019-07-30T17:53:11.422822 #1] DEBUG -- : [9a567258-d2de-48da-9f89-080bd5a57a2e] foo_path=/foo
D, [2019-07-30T17:53:11.422905 #1] DEBUG -- : [9a567258-d2de-48da-9f89-080bd5a57a2e] foo_url=http://myapp.com, myapp.com/foo
I, [2019-07-30T17:53:11.423239 #1]  INFO -- : [9a567258-d2de-48da-9f89-080bd5a57a2e] Redirected to http://myapp.com, myapp.com/foo
```

What could cause this behavior?

---

## UPDATE

After applying @Benj comment to use

```
url_options = { host: 'myapp.com', protocol: 'https' }
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = url_options
config.action_controller.default_url_options = url_options
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = url_options
```

Having

```
Rails.logger.debug("HERE admin_root_path #{admin_root_path}")
Rails.logger.debug("HERE admin_root_url #{admin_root_url}")
Rails.logger.debug("HERE new_session_path #{new_session_path}")
Rails.logger.debug("HERE new_session_url #{new_session_url}")
Rails.logger.debug("HERE root_url #{root_url}")
Rails.logger.debug("HERE Rails.configuration.action_mailer.default_url_options #{Rails.configuration.action_mailer.default_url_options}")
Rails.logger.debug("HERE Rails.configuration.action_controller.default_url_options #{Rails.configuration.action_controller.default_url_options}")
Rails.logger.debug("HERE Rails.configuration.default_url_options #{Rails.configuration.try(:default_url_options).inspect}")
Rails.logger.debug("HERE Rails.configuration.app_domain #{Rails.configuration.try(:app_domain).inspect}")
Rails.logger.debug("HERE Rails.application.routes.default_url_options #{Rails.application.routes.default_url_options}")

redirect_to admin_root_path
```

outputs

```
D, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.461467 #1] DEBUG -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] HERE admin_root_path /admin
D, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.461605 #1] DEBUG -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] HERE admin_root_url https://myapp.com/admin
D, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.461728 #1] DEBUG -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] HERE new_session_path /session
D, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.461840 #1] DEBUG -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] HERE new_session_url https://myapp.com/session
D, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.461934 #1] DEBUG -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] HERE root_url https://myapp.com/
D, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.462000 #1] DEBUG -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] HERE Rails.configuration.action_mailer.default_url_options {:host=>"myapp.com", :protocol=>"https"}
D, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.462050 #1] DEBUG -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] HERE Rails.configuration.action_controller.default_url_options {:host=>"myapp.com", :protocol=>"https"}
D, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.462104 #1] DEBUG -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] HERE Rails.configuration.default_url_options nil
D, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.462158 #1] DEBUG -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] HERE Rails.configuration.app_domain nil
D, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.462215 #1] DEBUG -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] HERE Rails.application.routes.default_url_options {:host=>"myapp.com", :protocol=>"https"}
I, [2019-07-31T07:50:36.462421 #1]  INFO -- : [33c730fe-8fe7-4873-99d3-aa77e6542287] Redirected to http://myapp.com, myapp.com/admin
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set your url options to `config.action_controller.default_url_options` too

in config/enviroments/production.rb:

```
url_options = { host: 'myapp.com', protocol: 'https' }
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = url_options
config.action_controller.default_url_options = url_options
```

Additionally if you have problems when using route helpers, you could also set:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = url_options
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked source code https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to

```
      def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {}) #:doc:
        raise ActionControllerError.new("Cannot redirect to nil!") if options.nil?

        if options.is_a?(Hash) && options[:status]
          status = options.delete(:status)
        elsif response_status[:status]
          status = response_status[:status]
        else
          status = 302
        end

        response.redirected_to = options

        case options
          # The scheme name consist of a letter followed by any combination of
          # letters, digits, and the plus ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-")
          # characters; and is terminated by a colon (":").
          when %r{^\w[\w\d+.-]*:.*}
            redirect_to_full_url(options, status)
          when String
            redirect_to_full_url(request.protocol + request.host_with_port + options, status)
          when :back
            if referer = request.headers["Referer"]
              redirect_to(referer, :status=>status)
            else
              raise RedirectBackError
            end
          else
            redirect_to_full_url(url_for(options), status)
        end
      end
```

I have checked `request.host_with_port`, this lead me to https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Request/raw_host_with_port

```
    def raw_host_with_port
      if forwarded = env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"]
        forwarded.split(/,\s?/).last
      else
        env['HTTP_HOST'] || "#{env['SERVER_NAME'] || env['SERVER_ADDR']}:#{env['SERVER_PORT']}"
      end
    end
```

I have found that in

`request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']` was empty, but `request.env['HTTP_HOST']` was `"myapp.com, myapp.com"`

thus I have added `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;`
 to nginx config

nginx condig before

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";

proxy_set_header   Host $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto http;
proxy_read_timeout 30;
```

nginx condig after

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";

proxy_set_header   Host $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto http;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_read_timeout 30;
```